# How to split text into words while only capturing full stops and spaces that come after full stops?

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I would like to split this text,

`"Tom works. Tom is a student. Bob is a student."`

into this,

`["Tom", "works", ".", " ", "Tom", "is", "a", "student", ".", " ", "Bob", "is", "a", "student", "."]`

I have tried `text.split(/(\.)(\s)/)` but I am unsure how to add splitting on spaces without capturing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on *non-captured* spaces, *or* on a captured period *and* optionally captured space, then filter out empty matches:

```js
console.log(
  "Tom works. Tom is a student. Bob is a student."
    .split(/ |(\.)(\s)?/)
    .filter(Boolean)
);
```

Another method, with `.match` instead of `split`, and using lookbehind:

```js
console.log(
  "Tom works. Tom is a student. Bob is a student."
    .match(/[^\s.]+|\.|(?<=\.) /g)
);
```